# Tensorflow asks inputs for unnecessary placeholders when using tf.cond()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Consider the following code snippet that includes tensorflow `tf.cond()`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

bb = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
xx = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='xx')
yy = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='yy')

zz = tf.cond(bb, lambda: xx + yy, lambda: 100 + yy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
        dict1 = {bb:False, yy:np.array([1., 3, 4]), xx:np.array([5., 6, 7])}
        print(sess.run(zz, feed_dict=dict1)) # works fine without errors

        dict2 = {bb:False, yy:np.array([1., 3, 4])}
        print(sess.run(zz, feed_dict=dict2)) # get an InvalidArgumentError asking to
                                             # provide an input for xx
```

In both cases, `bb` is `False` and evaluation of `zz` theoretically has no dependency on `xx`, but still tensorflow requires an input for `xx`. Even though it can be provided as a dummy array, it has to be matched with the shape of `yy` and is not as clean as `dict2`.

Can anybody suggest how to evaluate `zz` (using `tf.cond()` or any other approach) without providing a value for `xx`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define `xx` as a `tf.Variable` instead, giving it a default value (which will be used whenever `xx` is not fed with another value). A few things to notice:

1. Although `xx` is not a placeholder - you can still treat it as if it were by feeding values into it through the `feed_dict`.
2. Use `validate_shape=False` so that you can feed any shapes into `xx`.
3. Use `trainable=False` so that `xx` is not optimized over (otherwise, an optimizer might change its default value to things like `Nan`, which may cause problems).
4. Don't forget to initialize the values for `xx`, by using, e.g., `tf.global_variables_initializer()`.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

bb = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
xx = tf.Variable(initial_value=0.0,validate_shape=False,trainable=False,name='xx')
yy = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='yy')

zz = tf.cond(bb, lambda: xx + yy, lambda: 100 + yy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   dict1 = {bb:False, yy:np.array([1., 3, 4]), xx:np.array([5., 6, 7])}
   print(sess.run(zz, feed_dict=dict1))
   dict2 = {bb:False, yy:np.array([1., 3, 4])}
   print(sess.run(zz, feed_dict=dict2))
```